# Call Javascript From C# in GeckoFX 33

Tags: c#, geckofx

Im trying to execute javascript call from C# to the Document loaded in GeckoFX controller, im doing this:

```
public void evaluateScript(string command)
{            
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("evaluateScript: " + command);
    using (Gecko.AutoJSContext context = 
        new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext))
    {
            string result;
            context.EvaluateScript(
                command, 
                (nsISupports)geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow, 
                out result);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, I only found as a solution to call `geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate('javascript:functionName(1,2);');` but with this, I can't recover return data from functionName and using the `Navigate` to make a JavaScript call I think is an error. Is there no way to call JavaScript functions in the DOM and receive their data in C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, in the version 33, the API has changed a little, its more simple, because by default the EvaluateScript get the WebBrowser DOM as default context if you pass the param, and return the result direct.

```
public void evaluateScript(string command)
        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("evaluateScript: " + command);
            using (Gecko.AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext))
            {
                var result = context.EvaluateScript(command, geckoWebBrowser1.Window.DomWindow);
            }
        }
```

In the older versions, need to specify the context of the EvaluateScript, i found examples in this URL: https://nhabuiduc.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/geckofx-net-webbrowser-setup-and-features/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the context in witch script is executed.

I thought about returning data to C#  thru JSON but if I execute "JSON.stringify({})" I get "" instead of "{}" as a return in c#